# VBA to convert excel data to array ready for highcharts

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel file with data that looks like the following, where row 3 is a number, and row 4 are excel dates. Rows 1 and 2 are empty.

```
        A  |  B   |  C  |  D  |
    -----------------------------
    1
    2
    3  22     23    15    9 
    4 44582 44263 44263 44265
```

I need to get the data into a string, formatted as an array, suitable for use with highcharts using VBA:

```
series1 = [
             ["12/12/21", 22],
             ["15/12/21", 23],
             ["17/12/21", 15],
             ....
          ]
```

Comment: What problem have you encountered? It would be better to formulate this as a question supported by some description of what you've already tried to solve it. StackOverflow is no good as a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Excel Rows to HighCharts String

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub stringHighChart()
    
    Const str1 As String = "series1 = ["
    Const FR As Long = 3
    Const FC As Long = 1
    
    Dim strLen As Long: strLen = Len(str1)
    Dim str2 As String: str2 = Space(strLen + 2) & "["""
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim LC As Long: LC = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Dim Data As Variant
        With .Cells(3, 1)
            Data = .Resize(2, LC - FC + 1).Value
        End With
        Dim Result As String: Result = str1 & vbLf
        Dim dValue As Date
        Dim c As Long
        For c = 1 To LC
            Result = Result & str2
            dValue = CDate(Data(2, c))
            Result = Result & Format(dValue, "dd\/mm\/yy") & """" & ", "
            Result = Result & Data(1, c) & "]," & vbLf
        Next c
        Result = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 2) & vbLf & Space(strLen - 1) & "]"
        Debug.Print Result
    End With

End Sub
```